# Return variable when call from nested backticks with @ARGV

Tags: perl, system-calls

In visudo Ubuntu I whitelist this program (I doing this way for security purpose, parameterized all commands)

```
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/App/Filter_Parameters_Wrap.pm *
```

In program.pl

```
my $capture = qx("/usr/bin/sudo /App/Filter_Parameters_Wrap.pm kernel_version");
```

In the module Filter_Parameters_Wrap:

```
my $fuction  = $ARGV[0];
print filters_dispatch($fuction) if defined $fuction;

sub filters_dispatch {
    my $filter = shift;

    my $dispatch = {
      kernel_version    => \&filter_kernel_version,
      };

    return $dispatch->{$filter}->();

}

sub filter_kernel_version {
   my $command = '/bin/uname -a';
   my $sudo = App::Sudo::Main_Sudo->root($command);
   utf8::decode($sudo);
   return $sudo;
}
```

This approach is working , but I have to do print in print filters_dispatch (print directly a variable string), so I can get the output of return of function `filter_kernel_version` in the variable $capture

In some cases inside the function `filter_kernel_version` I want to create a hash and return as anonymous hash without print directly, but this way is not working

can you recommend a better approach?

Comment: If you need to run a different Perl (because of sudo), this is probably a good approach. Just return a JSON or Data::Dumper of the hash and deserialize it back to a has.

Comment: You can't return anything from backticks. You can print, and capture the output. If you need to return a data structure, consider serialising it. JSON would probably work well for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what option you use to communicate between processes, you'll be limited to sending a sequence of bytes. This means that you will need to *serialize* your hash somehow. Encoding it using JSON (e.g. using [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS)) might be a simple way of doing that.